# how to convert 24-hour format TimeSpan to 12-hour format TimeSpan?

Tags: c#

I have TimeSpan data represented as 24-hour format, such as 14:00:00, I wanna convert it to 12-hour format, 2:00 PM, I googled and found something related in stackoverflow and msdn, but didn't solve this problem, can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

**Update**
Seems that it's possible to convert 24-hour format TimeSpan to String, but impossible to convert the string to 12-hour format TimeSpan :(

But I still got SO MANY good answers, thanks!

Comment: Can you provide your code.. to understand your problem..

Comment: Its not really clear can you elaborate a little. Timespan is not absolute time so you can not represent it in AM/PM. So 14:00:00 does not appear to be Timespan is it just time stored in a string variable in this format?

Comment: This [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) will help

Comment: To me the question is quite clear. When doing `ToString` on the `TimeSpan` 14:00:00 the string `14:00:00` is returned. The question is what is required to instead return `2:00:00 PM`? (And an answer for this interpretation of the question has been provided.)

Comment: @MartinLiversage, the return value is also an TimeSpan object, 2:00 PM, thanks

Comment: uh....just convert TimeSpan object "14:00:00" to TimeSpan object "2:00 PM"..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) represents a time *interval* not a time of day. The [`DateTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) structure is more likely what you're looking for.

Comment: Actually `TimeSpan` is quite suitable to represent a time of day as long as you make sure that `TotalDays < 1`. The operator overloads allow you to easily compute things like the `DateTime` for an event at a specific date and a given `TimeSpan` representing a time of day. Also `DateTime.TimeOfDay` will return a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Many good points, though requires a slight change in mindset about how the time is represented. It's confusing to think that the type `DateTime` returns to represent a time of day could potentially have a value which actually spans _multiple days_ (though logically never would).

Answer (score 36):

(Summing up my scattered comments in a single answer.)

First you need to understand that `TimeSpan` represents a time interval. This time interval is internally represented as a count of ticks an not the string `14:00:00` nor the string `2:00 PM`. Only when you convert the `TimeSpan` to a string does it make sense to talk about the two different string representations. Switching from one representation to another does not alter or convert the tick count stored in the `TimeSpan`.

Writing time as `2:00 PM` instead of `14:00:00` is about date/time formatting and culture. This is all handled by the `DateTime` class.

However, even though `TimeSpan` represents a time interval it is quite suitable for representing the time of day (`DateTime.TimeOfDay` returns a `TimeSpan`). So it is not unreasonable to use it for that purpose. (However, `TimeOnly` was added in .NET 6.0 and is better suited to represent the time of day now.)

To perform the formatting described you need to either rely on the formatting logic of `DateTime` or simply create your own formatting code.

- Using `DateTime`:

  ```
    var dateTime = new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks); // Date part is 01-01-0001
    var formattedTime = dateTime.ToString("h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ```

  The format specifiers using in `ToString` are documented on the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) page on MSDN. It is important to specify a `CultureInfo` that uses the desired AM/PM designator. Otherwise the `tt` format specifier may be replaced by the empty string.
- Using custom formatting:

  ```
    var (hours, amPmDesignator) = timeSpan.Hours switch
    {
        0 => (12, "AM"),
        12 => (12, "PM"),
        > 12 => (timeSpan.Hours - 12, "PM"),
        _ => (timeSpan.Hours, "AM"),
    };
    var formattedTime = $"{hours}:{timeSpan.Minutes:00} {amPmDesignator}";
  ```

  Admittedly this solution is a bit more complex compared to the first method.

Comment: wow...so detailed answer, 2 solutions, and custom format tutorial on MSDN...thanks a lot!

Comment: This solution helped me the best.  My formattedTime variable looked like this:
`var formattedTime =
              String.Format("{0}{1}", hours, amPmDesignator);`

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the TimeSpan to a DateTime object first, then use whatever [DateTime format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) you need:

```
var t = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

Console.WriteLine(new DateTime(t.Ticks).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt"));
```

`ToShortTimeString()` would also work, but it's regional-settings dependent so it would not display correctly (or correctly, depending on how you see it) on non-US systems.

Comment: You need to specify a `CultureInfo` like `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` in the `ToString` call to avoid problems when the current culture uses a 24 hour time format (in that case the format specifier `tt` inserts an empty string).

Answer (score 7):

`TimeSpan` represents a time interval (a difference between times),
not a date or a time, so it makes little sense to define it in 24 or 12h format. I assume that you actually want a `DateTime`.

For example 2 PM of today:

```
TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromHours(14);
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today.Add(ts);
```

Then you can format that date as you want:

```
String formatted = String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss}", dt); // "12.4.1012 02:00:00" - german (de-DE)
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 5):

Try This Code:

```
int timezone = 0;
```

This string gives 12-hours format

```
string time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-timezone).ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

This string gives 24-hours format

```
string time = DateTime.Now.AddHours(-timezone).ToString("HH:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are staying in a 24 hour range, you can achieve what you want by subtracting the negative `TimeSpan` from Today's `DateTime` (or any date for that matter), then strip the date portion:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
dt.Subtract(-TimeSpan.FromHours(14)).ToShortTimeString();
```

Yields:

2:00 PM

Answer (score 1):

```
String formatted = yourDateTimeValue.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
```

Answer (score 1):

It is very simple, 
Let's suppose we have an object ***ts*** of TimesSpan : 
`TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan();`
and suppose it contains some value like 14:00:00
Now first convert this into a string  and then in DateTime 
as following:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(); // this is object of TimeSpan and Suppose it contains
                              // value 14:00:00
string tIme = ts.ToString(); // here we convert ts into String and Store in Temprary
                             // String variable.
 DateTime TheTime = new DateTime(); // Creating the object of DateTime;
 TheTime = Convert.ToDateTime(tIme); // now converting our temporary string into DateTime;
 Console.WriteLine(TheTime.ToString(hh:mm:ss tt));
```

this will show the Result as: **02:00:00 PM**

Answer (score 0):

Normal Datetime can be converted in either 24 or 12 hours format.

For 24 hours format - MM/dd/yyyy **HH**:mm:ss tt

For 12 hours format - MM/dd/yyyy **hh**:mm:ss tt

There is a difference of captial and small H.

```
dateTimeValue.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```